# Firepad text editor - text area not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firepad

I'm following the instruction from [here](https://github.com/firebase/firepad/blob/master/examples/richtext-simple.html) to create a firepad editor.

my code is:

```js
    function init() {
      var firepadRef = getExampleRef();
      var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad-container'), {
        lineWrapping: true
      });
      var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, {
        richTextToolbar: true,
        richTextShortcuts: true
      });
      firepad.on('ready', function() {
        if (firepad.isHistoryEmpty()) {
          firepad.setHtml('<span style="font-size: 24px;">Rich-text editing with <span style="color: red">Firepad!</span></span><br/><br/>Collaborative-editing made easy.\n');
        }
      });
    }

    function getExampleRef() {
      var ref = new Firebase('https://firepad.firebaseio-demo.com');
      var hash = window.location.hash.replace(/#/g, '');
      if (hash) {
        ref = ref.child(hash);
      } else {
        ref = ref.push();
        window.location = window.location + '#' + ref.key(); // add it as a hash to the URL.
      }
      return ref;
    }
    init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>

  <!-- CodeMirror -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.2.0/codemirror.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.2.0/codemirror.css" />

  <!-- Firepad -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.2.0/firepad.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.2.0/firepad.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-content">
  <div id="firepad-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is i got the button for option as shown in the figure.

[image]

but the text field is not coming, even i mention the correct `id`. The original will be like this.

[image]

what i'm doing wrong. is there any other text editor available to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of firebase pad:

```js
function init() {
  //// Initialize Firebase.
  var firepadRef = getExampleRef();
  // TODO: Replace above line with:
  // var firepadRef = new Firebase('<YOUR FIREBASE URL>');

  //// Create CodeMirror (with lineWrapping on).
  var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad-container'), {
    lineWrapping: true
  });

  //// Create Firepad (with rich text toolbar and shortcuts enabled).
  var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, {
    richTextToolbar: true,
    richTextShortcuts: true
  });

  //// Initialize contents.
  firepad.on('ready', function() {
    if (firepad.isHistoryEmpty()) {
      firepad.setHtml('<span style="font-size: 24px;">Rich-text editing with <span style="color: red">Firepad!</span></span><br/><br/>Collaborative-editing made easy.\n');
    }
  });
}

// Helper to get hash from end of URL or generate a random one.
function getExampleRef() {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://firepad.firebaseio-demo.com');
  var hash = window.location.hash.replace(/#/g, '');
  if (hash) {
    ref = ref.child(hash);
  } else {
    ref = ref.push(); // generate unique location.
    window.location = window.location + '#' + ref.key(); // add it as a hash to the URL.
  }
  return ref;
}

init();
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
    background-color:#c00000;
  }
  /* Height / width / positioning can be customized for your use case.
         For demo purposes, we make firepad fill the entire browser. */
  #firepad-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#c5c5c5;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>

<!-- CodeMirror -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.2.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.2.0/codemirror.css" />

<!-- Firepad -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.2.0/firepad.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.2.0/firepad.min.js"></script>
<body style="border:2px;margin:50px;padding:5px;">
<div id="firepad-container"></div>
</body>
```

Edit: If you are putting the `firepad-container` within another div then set a height to that div to avoid `height:0px;` (and hence text-area being hidden)

Refer : [Firepad example](http://codepen.io/animenon/pen/eZQzMY)

Comment: thanks.. it's working to my code too. The problem is while adding it the page   it showing only the option as i mentioned

Comment: Thats probably because you are putting the `firepad-container` div with-in another `div`. If you intend to do that, set a height of that div so that the editor text-area doesn't have a `0px` height.

Comment: @m2j I think you got your answer, accept the answer. Read - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)