# Firepad text not shown until first click

Tags: javascript, css, firepad

I have embedded Fire Pad on my website. Initially I had problems with textbox being hidden but based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966467/firepad-text-editor-text-area-not-showing), I was able to make it work.

Everything seems to be working but one part. I need to click on the text area for text to be loaded for the first time. Ie. when page loads, the text area is visible but empty. I click in that text area and the document appears.

[DOM View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGfiN.jpg)

I can see text is available in the DOM it is just hidden until I focus on that area. I assume it is still related to my DOM structure and CSS.

I tried to fire focus and click events.. No luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here us what worked for me:

```js
codeMirror.focus();
codeMirror.setCursor(codeMirror.lineCount(), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `init();` to your

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}
```